# Test Boolean Values in python with single output value

Tags: python, list, testing

I have a list which has different Boolean values.

```
x = [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False]
```

i want to check that if there is any value in the list is "False" then I want a final output value to be "True". If there is no "False" or all "True" value then the final output will be "False".

Something like this,

```
#x has False value 
#>>> a = True (a is a variable)
# x doesn't have False or all True
#>>> a = False
```

Please help!

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 foreach (bool myBool in inputBool) {
               if (myBool = false)
              {
            // as soon as a false is found you can return true and break the loop
            return true;
             }       
        }
        // if no false is found 
          return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple with the `all` built-in function:

```
x = [True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False]
print (not all(x))

print (not all([]) )
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,

this is working but it is giving me a list of values where all of them are False. I need one single value. If the list is containing any False value then the output value should say "True" (one boolean value)

Comment: Please show your code; in my code, both interactive and script, these produce a single each each, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can simply do:

```
a = False in x
```